# RewriteRule not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use a rewirte rule in .htaccss so when a user enters "/page/my-name", it will direct him to "file.php?name=my-name"

I use the following:

```
RewriteRule ^page/?$ file.php?name=1 [NC,L]
```

However, it redirects me only when I go to "/page" and not when i'm going to "/page/my-name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule includes the `$` anchor, meaning the request string has to end there.  That is not actually what you want, since you want to capture anything after the `/` and use it in your substitution.

Perhaps try something like this?

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*) file.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

Also, note, you had `=1` in your question, instead of `=$1`.